# Where do I put mods for Garry's Mod?

Tags: steam, mods, garrys-mod

I want to install the DarkRP addon for Garry's Mod but I can't find my Profile folder in the steamapps folder. Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with DarkRP, but for all non-Workshop addons I've ever used, you put them in `steamapps/common/GarrysMod/garrysmod/addons`. If it *is* on the Workshop, just subscribe to it and it will be installed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Are you downloading the legacy version of DarkRP from Garrysmod.org? If that is the case,  the garrysmod folder is now located in

> Program files\Steam\steamapps\common\GarrysMod\garrysmod

Also, you will need to change the text file name inside the DarkRP folder from `info.txt` to `addon.txt`. Once that's done, just drop it in the `addons` folder.

However, I suggest you use the in-game addon browser and download the latest version of DarkRP from the Workshop. It is more convenient, as it applies updates and patches automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just install maps, mods, gamemodes and more with 1 click by using the Steam Workshop. I don't know though if DarkRP is in there.